# The view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this error in an MVC app:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/User/Index.aspx
>
> ~/Views/User/Index.ascx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx

I don't understand why it's coming up; I'm not trying to navigate to an Index view; I'm trying to navigate to a ChangeExpiredPassword route. The code for the ChangeExpiredPassword controller action is executing, but as soon as control passes out of that method, this error is thrown from the internals of MVC. I have no idea why we're trying to redirect to Index all of a sudden. I don't know what code would be relevant to share but I can add code upon request. Thanks!

edit: here is how we are getting to ChangeExpiredPassword, this is from a `UserController` class:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    if (pwExpirationDate < DateTime.Now)
    {
        return ChangeExpiredPassword();
    }
    ...
}
```

and here is the ChangeExpiredPassword itself, minus some HTML building code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeExpiredPassword()
{
    ActionResult actionResult = null;

    try
    {
        ContentViewModel viewModel = new ContentViewModel();

        Form form = new Form();
        form.Method = FormMethod.Post;
        form.Action = "User/ChangeExpiredPassword";

        // this is where we build some HTML for the Change Expired Password view

        viewModel.ContentControls.Add(form);

        actionResult = View(viewModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
        actionResult = Error();
    }

    return actionResult;
}
```

Comment: What does the controller class and this particular action method do?  What route is being requested?  If this is an `Index` action and it's returning a view then, well, it'll look for an `Index` view.

Comment: Oh, we are on an Index action actually - it's just redirecting to ChangeExpiredPassword if the user's password is expired. I'll add some relevant code so you can see.

Comment: What is `ChangeExpiredPassword()`?  What does it return?  It sounds like it's returning a `View()`.  So I guess the question becomes... What do you want to happen at the end of this `Index` action?  What should be returned to the user?

Comment: HttpGet, HttpPost... this is fishy, if you want to redirect,  use RedirectToAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ChangeExpiredPassword` is itself an action, and if that action ends with this:

```
return View();
```

Then returning `ChangeExpiredPassword()` tries to return a view.  *However*, the view chosen by the framework is based on the route being requested, *not* the method being called.  From the framework's perspective, you're returning `View()` from within `Index`.

It sounds like you want to *redirect* the user to `ChangeExpiredPassword`.  Which in your `Index` action would look more like this:

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(ChangeExpiredPassword));
```

This will instruct the browser to initiate a new `GET` request for the `ChangeExpiredPassword` action.  Which, semantically, is what you want to happen.  There's no need to try to get clever with returning highly custom responses.  Keep each request/response simple and RESTful.  The response from `Index` is instructing the client "you need to go to `ChangeExpiredPassword`".